# MakeMSI Integrate Application required Runtime in Application Setup

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer

I hope someone may be familiar with [MakeMSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MakeMsi). I got the problem that my application needs to run a special runtime, whose executable I have as an MSI-File.

It's not a big deal to set the Custom Action to execute this file, after all files were copied to the harddrive, but the problem is, that no installation process can be executed, while another installation process is running ... I tried to set the custom action after the installation process is finalized, but this is not allowed ...

Does anyone have experience with that or knows a way out?

I'm very thankful for all well-meant and helpful answers, so thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run two concurrent MSI installs, that's the issue you've found. It seems like this other MSI might be a prerequisite, like the NET runtime, C++ support, SQL Express and so on, and these get installed with a prerequisite installer that runs before your install, a bootstrapper.

Alternatively, if this special runtime is only for you (and not all users of the system) and if MakeMsi can generate a merge module then make a merge module and include it in your MSI build like other runtime merge modules can be included (such as .msm files from Microsoft).

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm right new with the issue of creating own installer, but thank you, I know what the merge function is and as far as I know, MakeMSI supports this.